# Are there any recent articles on the current state of Case theory?

Tags: syntax, morphology, inflection, cases

Specifically I'm interested in the split between Structural Case and Morphological case.

Structural Case has been part of Chomskyan syntactic theory since at least [Government & Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_and_binding_theory) (GB). Roughly, Case Theory in GB and the minimalist program state that all nominals in a grammatical sentence must have Structural Case and they move away from their base positions to get it.

Morphological case, or m-case, is the more familiar case (nominative, accusative, dative) that surfaces phonologically on nominals in languages which do so. The most recent theories of m-case that I am aware of derive from Alec Marantz's 1991 paper "Case and Licensing" (which was later reissued as an intro to [Reuland (2000)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=blno4uttFO8C)).

When I last checked, Nominative and Accusative were assumed to be Structural Case and the rest were sort of up in the air.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you know so far about these concepts?

Comment: Indeed, it will be better to explain what you know so far and what would you like to know specifically. As per the [FAQ](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), we don't encourage open-ended questions.

Comment: @LouisRhys I wouldn't consider this question open-ended, as I know exactly what would constitute an answer ("X is currently working on it?" or "It was investigated in paper Y by Z"). you're right, I suppose I should give a bit more background, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by the word "recent" (i.e. how much you already know).

By the way you worded your question, I assume you're interested in generative syntax? If so, see references in Pesetsky and Torrego's [2011 article](http://web.mit.edu/linguistics/people/faculty/pesetsky/Case_chapter.pdf) in *The Oxford Handbook of Linguistic Minimalism*, Bobaljik and Wurmbrand's [2011 article](http://wurmbrand.uconn.edu/Papers/Case.pdf) in *The Oxford Handbook of Case*, and chapter 4 in *Theories of case* by Miriam Butt (2006).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can consult a good reference about case and checking in Minimalism. There is a book called "[Flexible Syntax: A Theory of Case and Arguments](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=91-D04Xphi0C)",  written by Ad Neeleman, Fred Weerman.