# Case of Nominal Associate in Clauses with Exceptional case-marking

Tags: cross-linguistic, cases

I've been wondering whether the nominal associate of expletive *there* gets nominative, accusative or dative case in clauses with exceptional case-marking in other languages, since case isn't visible outside the pronoun paradigm in English.

> I want there<sub>1</sub> [<sub>TP</sub> t<sub>1</sub> to be sandwiches<sub>NOM/ACC/DAT?</sub> at the party]

Comment: Hmm ... I was curious about something similar a while back (not clauses with expletive "there" specifically, but predicate NPs); I don't know if the sources cited in my question might possibly be of some use: [Are there any universals about how m-case can pattern for predicate NPs?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25848/are-there-any-universals-about-how-m-case-can-pattern-for-predicate-nps)

Comment: @sumelic That sounds like an interesting question which closely relates to this one. Thanks for linking it to this question.

Comment: I got a hunch it's nominative because the verb `to be`. It's not going to let `want` or any other verb assign case to its argument. I'm sure someone else can give you an answer that's not based on a hunch though.

Comment: @Wilson Yeah. Just wondering because back in the day, the nominal associate was said to absorb case from the expletive via an expletive-argument chain. So, if the claim is true and the expletive obtains ACC from the ECM verb, it should show up on the nominal associate then.

Comment: Can you clarify the term "nominal associate"? A quick search showed you question as the only thing on the first page which had anything to do with linguistics.

Comment: @Wilson It's the argument of the verb in, say, an existential construction with expletive 'there'. The DP is said to be the associate of the expletive. In constructions with expletive 'it', a clause is said to be the associate of the expletive.

Comment: So the "nominal associate" is the thing that gets extraposed when the dummy is inserted in subject position.

Answer (score 1):

As the Wikipaedia article suggests, the objective case is typical for such nominals. In Latin and Greek, for example, the accusative case is used—although neither language normally has this expletive *there* expressed as a special word, the below is semantically identical to using English *there is/are*:

> Dicit **viros** adesse [acc. mascl. plural]

"He says men to be present = He says that there are men (there/present)".

It is the same in Ancient Greek.

In English, the objective case is used in similar constructions (though without your sense of *there*):

> He is there --> I want **him** to be there.
>
> He is a teacher --> I want **him** to be a teacher.

It is clear that *<s>I want he to be there</s> is unacceptable. Both these examples and your example are historically the same construction in English.

It is the same in Dutch, with the sense of *there* you are looking for (*er*):

> Hij was er --> Ik zag **hem** er zijn [note that the construction is a little bit contrived with this particular sense of the verb and the pronoun combined, but it's possible].

"He was there" --> "I saw him there be = I saw him be there".